# Django + Nginx 500 error when fetching static content

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn

I am having trouble serving static content using Django, Nginx and Gunicorn. I can serve media files (images) from my /media/ folder, as well as html, but the static requests to the /static/ folder are producing 500 errors.

I ran collectstatic to collect all static in /opt/myapp/myapp/myapp/static/

Here is my Nginx configuration:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name <ip_address>;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /static/ {
            alias /opt/myapp/myapp/myapp/static/;
    }

    location = /media/ {
            alias /opt/myapp/myapp/myapp/media/;
    }


    location / {
            include proxy_params;
            proxy_pass http://unix:/opt/myapp/myapp/myapp/myapp.sock;
    }
}
```

And the Django urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^', include('core.urls')),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
]  + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT) 
   + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Django settings.py:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    '/opt/myapp/myapp/myapp/core/static',
]

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))), 'static')
```

And a sample from the Nginx access.log (there are no errors in error.log):

```
"GET /static/markup/css/index.css HTTP/1.1" 500 63893 "http://104.131.44.215/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36"
```

Comment: Does nginx or gunicorn report any errors in the error log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What does your settings.py look like?

EDIT:

1. Look once again at your code. In Nginx you have different path unlike the settings.py!
2. You have probably misunderstood the Django docs (staticfiles_dirs vs static_root)
3. Your STATICFILES_DIRS should look like this

`STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)`

4. If this won't work, alter your STATIC_ROOT (must be a different path than the staticfiles_dirs) and don't forget to run collectstatic

Comment: I added the static lines in settings.py above

Comment: From what I understand my staticfiles_dir should contain paths to the app's static files, which are here: '/opt/myapp/myapp/myapp/core/static'. Then, when I run collectstatic they are all placed here, at the static root: os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))), 'static'). Then, my Nginx should contain a link to os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))), 'static'), right?

Comment: Nevermind, I clearly didn't understand the point of staticfiles dirs

Comment: That fixed it! Thank you!

Comment: Yes, the "staticfiles_dirs" contains static data (css, js, img) ONLY for developmenout (in your network or localhost, NO Nginx used), but it's usually placed next to apps dir and the project dir (e.g. myapp/static, NO myapp/core/static). Your defined STATIC_ROOT variable is weird, I have never seen something like that. It's usually STATIC_ROOT = "path/to/static/in/production", NO os.path.join(os.path blablablabla) ... Don't forget mark my post above as helpful :-).